# Take images as quickly as possible from RPi Camera and send to MATLAB for processing?

Tags: camera, raspicam, matlab

I'm using an RPi camera module in conjunction with an RPi 3 (Stretch) to track quick motion - I want to capture images as fast as possible (quick = minimum 30 fps) and send to MATLAB image by image for further processing. Any way I can do this?

Comment: stream the video over lan

Comment: How do I do that?

Comment: Uh...that is not a relevant link. Could you check?

Comment: i could search the internet and find out how to stream video from RPi

Comment: My mistake I posted on the wrong question - sorry

Comment: Obviously I can figure out how to stream video from the RPi. The real question is, how do I send it frame by frame to MATLAB?

Comment: @P_Lash Can't MATLAB process a video stream?

Comment: I am using a command like `raspiyuv -w 128 -h 96 --nopreview -awb fluorescent -bm -tl 0 -o -` from the command line to send raw image data to std out but the best frame rate I can get is about 4Hz.